# Is it possible to post in chatroom without entering?

Tags: support

Is it possible to post in chatroom without entering? For example, by sending some requests using web api? Some javascript library required for logging into the chatroom has not been loadable.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't expect chat to work without being logged in, based on the [requirement to have 20 reputation points](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

Re: your update of *"by sending some requests using web api"*, I have looked at only one (Java-based) SE chat API client, and it required a login, but that particular one uses a plain text file, so that might avoid your JavaScript issue. I *think* it was from https://github.com/Tunaki/chatexchange but I don't have a way of confirming at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

### Stack Exchange requires logins for the ability to use our chat rooms.

Chat doesn't allow for anonymous participation. To make posts in the chat room you must enter the room itself.